# How to break out of function and back into loop?

Tags: python

I am currently making a web builder where it will generate a random gif based on the GIPHY API. I am having a problem where I test a case on when the api returns with 0 results.

```
def get_image_link(link):
global flag
set_count = 0
r = requests.get(link)
api_response = json.loads(r.text)
response = api_response['data']
if not response:
    print('GIPHY API returned no results... finding another word...')
    pass
elif response:
    for set in response:
        set_count += 1
    random_gif_num = random.randint(0, set_count) - 1
    try:
        flag = True
        return response[random_gif_num]['images']['original']['url']
    except TypeError:
        print(TypeError + '... rerunning application...')
        pass
```

`while not flag:
    get_image_link(get_random_query())`

Essentially, if the results come back with no data in the results, i want it to retry the function to grab another word. The program works when a word with results comes back but when it comes back with 0 results I get a `TypeError` and it doesn't go back into the loop. I am sure it does this because it doesn't break out of the function and instead returns a `[]` type. How can I break out of the function and get back into the while loop so I can generate another result? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can move catching exception outside the function i.e:

```
while not flag:
    try:
       get_image_link(get_random_query())
    except TypeError:
        flag = False
        print('TypeError... rerunning application...')
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, even when it runs and tries to find another word I still get a TypeError and it stops the file. Any idea why?

Comment: @Lewis My guess, it's not related to exception but to `flag` variable which is set to `True` fro some reason

Comment: The get_image_link() is being called somewhere else. Do you think the response variable is able to access the other part of the loop even when it is equal to []?

Answer (score 2):

Reset flag to false!

```
try:
    flag = True
    return response[random_gif_num]['images']['original']['url']
except TypeError:
    flag = false
    print(TypeError + '... rerunning application...')
    pass
```

Comment: I gave this a try and a lot of the times it works, however, on some occasions ill get the TypeError and it cancels out my code. Any idea why?

Comment: @Lewis the problem is the print, there you try to concatenate `TypeError` a exception object with a string, which make no sense, change it to something like `print('TypeError ... rerunning application...')`